# Invalid key path in IndexedDB: restrictions?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, key-value-store

I'm trying to create a really simple IndexedDB with some JavaScript, but it fails in the on handler already. Apparently the browser (Chrome 57) is not able to [parse](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/147e1b042ffe6bd831960cdae310ccfc58606e51/Source/WebCore/Modules/indexeddb/IDBKeyPath.cpp#L132) the `keyPath` (in [Basic Concepts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB)) of my storage.

I'm following more or less these simple examples: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB#Creating_or_updating_the_version_of_the_database) or [Opera-Dev](https://dev.opera.com/articles/introduction-to-indexeddb/).

Suppose I want to store objects like this one in the DB:

```
{
    "1": 23, // the unique id
    "2": 'Name',
    "3": 'Description',
    "4": null,
    "5": null
}
```

Here is the code:

```
var sStoreNodes = 'nodes';
var sIdFieldNode = '1'; // the important part

// event is fired for creating the DB and upgrading the version
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event)
{
    var db = event.target.result;

    // Create an objectStore for nodes. Unique key should be the id of the node, on property 1. 
    // So ID will be the key!
    var objectStore =  db.createObjectStore(
        sStoreNodes,
        {
            // changing to a plain string works, if it is a valid identifier and not just a strigified number
            'keyPath'       : [ sIdFieldNode ],
            'autoIncrement' : false // really important here
        });
};
```

The error message reads like:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createObjectStore' on 'IDBDatabase': The keyPath option is not a valid key path.
>       at IDBOpenDBRequest.CCapIndexedDB.request.onupgradeneeded

I can also try to leave out the key path, but I'm wondering why this happens and want can I do about it, if I really need to use a (complex) key path.

Regarding the spec:

I'm not sure, whether [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-valid-key) can be applied here:

> A value is said to be a valid key if it is one of the following ECMAScript [ECMA-262] types: Number primitive value, String primitive value, Date object, or Array object.

and what [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBObjectStore-keyPath) actually means:

> If the key path is a DOMString, the value [for getting the key path] will be a DOMString equal to the key path. If the key path is a sequence, the value will be a new Array, populated by appending Strings equal to each DOMString in the sequence.

---

**Edit** This works, if you don't use a stringified number, but a string instead, which is a valid identifier (beginning with a character [a-zA-Z]). So `'keyPath' : 'b'` is OK. I guess this is because this value is used for creating paths like `a.b.c`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is the definition of a key path, from the spec:](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#key-path-construct)

> A key path is a DOMString or sequence that defines how to extract a key from a value. A valid key path is one of:
>
> - An empty DOMString.
> - An identifier, which is a DOMString matching the IdentifierName production from the ECMAScript Language Specification [ECMA-262].
> - A DOMString consisting of two or more identifiers separated by periods (ASCII character code 46).
> - A non-empty sequence containing only DOMStrings conforming to the above requirements.

For a string containing an integer, clearly the first, third, and fourth options do not apply. For the second, we have to see [what an IdentifierName is](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-IdentifierName), which is a little complicated, but basically it has to start with a letter, underscore, or dollar sign. This means that a string containing just an integer is not a valid key path.

If you really do have an object where the primary key is in a field whose name is a string containing an integer, you can either rename the field or not use key paths (in which case you have to manually specify the key as the second argument to `IDBObjectStore.add` and `IDBObjectStore.put`).

You linked to [the definition for a key](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-valid-key), which defines the valid values that a key can have (like for an object `{a: 1}` where the key path is `'a'` the key is `1`, which is valid).

The [other thing you linked to](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBObjectStore-keyPath) is about key paths like `a.b.c` referencing `{a: {b: {c: 1}}}`.